# How to create custom XHTML template system in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

*Hey guys, I want to know how to create a custom XHTML system with the custom module or via core file system in Magento 2 & how it works?*

Comment: Do you need xhtml for what purpose?

Comment: please refer this url, https://amasty.com/blog/how-to-use-ui-components-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

The good choice is use custom module if you need add extra customises.
Inside new module you can define your own template xhtml for your custom ui_component. Use default magento component or reused with additionals is depends on your requirements

Path usually

```
app/code/YourBrand/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/yourtemplatecomponent.xhtml
```

With new template. In your custom ui-component defined in layout you can define new template via tag item

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/yourtemplatecomponent</item>
</argument>
```

Example data of htmlContent component default magento

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/ProductVideo/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml#L10